# Writing sections of a list on separate lines in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm attempting to create a program that will take a list and write out all it's elements on separate lines in a group of **N** elements per line.

e.g. user queries `print(3,[a,s,d,t,s,t]).`

Prolog writes:

```
asd
tst
```

I got stuck at the point where the program lists first (N) elements but doesn't proceed to the next line. Could anyone help to pinpoint me to my mistake?

```
print(N,[H|T]):-
    N>=1,
    write(H),
    N1 is N-1,
    print(N1,T),
    nl,
    print(N,T).
```

Comment: Your immediate mistake is that you have no base case. You should have an if-then-else after the comparison (`>=`), and some more stuff.

Comment: Sorry, Thomas, I don't understand. I tried to work with a base case (both for an empty list and for I>N) but unfortunately, it all took me only far away from the desired outcome.

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two numbers, as you have to start over from `N` at each new line. Also, two base cases (end of line, end of list).

```
print(N,L):-
  print(N,N,L).

print(N,I,[H|T]):-
  ( I >= 1 ->
    write(H),
    I1 is I-1,
    print(N,I1,T)
  ; nl,
    print(N,N,[H|T]) ).
print(_,_,[]).
```

Comment: THANK YOU, Thomas!! This is exactly what I was trying to get to!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using `length/2` and `append/3`. It's transparent, but I think it's a little heavy-handed compared to Tomas' solution.

```
print_substring([]).
print_substring([H|T]) :-
    write(H),
    print_substring(T).

print_substrings(N, L) :-
    length(S, N),
    (   append(S, R, L)
    ->  print_substring(S), nl,
        print_substrings(N, R)
    ;   print_substring(L), nl
    ).
```

Which results in:

```
| ?-  print_substrings(3, [a,b,c,d,e]).
abc
de

yes
| ?-
```

NOTE: When you choose names for variables or predicates, it's good to avoid very generic names, like `print`. `print` happens to be a library predicate in some Prologs, so creating a predicate of that name in your own code can lead to a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your code in two parts. First function `print/2`, is the API, and `print/3` will be your main function.

`print/2` will take an integer and a list of atoms and calls `print/3`.

```
print(N, L) :-
  print(N, L, []).
```

`print/3` and `print/2` are practically the same, except `print/3` will take a `Buffer` (as list) in last argument:

```
% if our list of atom is empty
% we just print Buf content and stop
print(_, [], Buf) :- 
  reverse(Buf, Atoms),
  atom_string(Atoms, String),
  format("~s~n", [String]).

% if our list of atom contain an head and tail
% we check if length of Buf is equal to N
print(N, [H|T], Buf) :-
  length(Buf, N), 
    % if its the case, we print our Buf and use
    % the rest of list of atoms
    reverse(Buf,Atoms), 
    atom_string(Atoms, String),
    format("~s~n", [String]), 
    print(N, [H|T])
  ;
    % else we take the head and concate it
    % with Buf.
    print(N, T, [H|Buf]).
```

You can test this code with `swipl` interpreter.

```
?- [myprint].
?- print((3,[a,s,f,t,s,t]).
asf
tst
?- print(4,[a,s,f,t,s,t]).
asft
st
```

Comment: This should probably be refactored to not depend upon `reverse/2`. Also, your conditional would be more reliable if you followed the canonical pattern using `->/2` and `;/2`: `( length(Buf, N) -> [if logic]  ; [else logic] )`.